# Error by selecting the parent of the input

Tags: jquery

Cloud you please answer me why I get an error by selecting the parent of the input by this way:

```
$("input:parent").css( "color", "red" );
```

Comment: `$("input").parent().css( "color", "red" );`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. but my question about this part "$("input:parent")". I am not searching for a solution. All other tags of HTML we can select them by this way !! $("HTML tag:parent")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery [`:parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selector selects elements that *are* a parent; it doesn't select the parent of an element. for that you want to use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

E.g. `$("input").parent().css( "color", "red" );`

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no parent selector in CSS3. The syntax `"input:parent"` is not valid and will not yield any results.

You can use jQueries `parent()` method as the comment suggested.